# Variable arguments in java

Tags: java, string, variadic-functions

I have the following classes:

```
public class WhereSqlClause{

    public static String build(String pattern, Object... args){
        //For instance, pattern = "Some string :placeholder"
        //and we call this method as WhereSqlClause.build(pattern, placeholder)
        //where placeholder was a local variable initialized before
    }

}
```

My question is how to replace all placeholders like `:placeholder` with the `placeholder.toString()` values.

For instance:

```
String pattern = "Some str another str:place  :holder";
Object place = "Place";
Object holder = "Holder";
String WhereSqlClause.build(pattern, place, holder);
//Have to produce "Some str Place another str Holder"
```

and

```
String pattern = "Some str :holder another str :place ";
Object place = "Place";
Object holder = "Holder";
String WhereSqlClause.build(pattern, place, holder);
//Have to produce "Some str Holder another str Place"
```

Comment: tried concatenation?

Comment: @Stultuske You didn;t understand. I want to know how to use local variable's name.

Comment: @St.Antario that's not type-safe.

Comment: @Pshemo I'm not. Please, look at the second example.

Comment: "I want to know how to use local variable's name." that is impossible. Java doesn't use variables by their names, but by their addresses. If you want to store some `name->value` pairs use `Map<String,Object>` instead of varargs.

Answer (score 0):

Example with a single string, after you just have to iterate over args...

```
//For instance, pattern = "Some string :placeholder"
//and we call this method as WhereSqlClause.build(pattern, placeholder)
//where placeholder was a local variable initialized before

StringBuilder sbPattern = new StringBuilder();
sbPattern.append(pattern);

// you get ":placeholder "
String placeholder = ":"+(String)args[0].toLowerCase() + " ";
// if is in the pattern, replace it
if (pattern.contains(placeholder)) {
    int i = pattern.indexOf(placeholder);
    sbPattern.replace(i, i + placeholder.length() , (String)args[0] + " ");
}
```

Comment: Strings are immutable. And even if they ware mutable what if placeholders would be `:foo` and `:fooBar`? With replacing `:foo` with value we will also get `valueBar` as result.

Comment: @Pshemo agreee... wait a minute for the fix.... about `:foobar` does not.... read my code...

Comment: "about :foobar does not.... read my code.." OK it will not because you are adding space ad the end of placeholder, but this solution is buggy if placeholder would be placed at end of pattern and will not have space after it.

Comment: as long as OP creates the pattern, I guess is a rule OP can follow to avoid issues and an easy sollution to fit needs...

Answer (score 0):

You can use MessageFormat, which can replace placeholders according to their positions.

You'll need a pattern of the form :

```
"some template with param {0} and another param {1}"
```

Then you can write :

```
public static String build (String pattern, Object... args)
{
    MessageFormat formatter = new MessageFormat (pattern);
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer (256);
    return formatter.format (args, output, null).toString();
}
```

Comment: Hm... I need to replace the placeholders like `:place` __iff__ the variable/field named `place` passed as an argument. How did you respect this case?

Comment: @St.Antario I don't think your exact requirement is possible. At least not with varags (the names of the variables are not available inside the method), so I suggested something similar that can be done easily. An alternative is to pass a `Map<String,String>` with placeholder names and their respective values, which will allow you to search for them in the pattern String and replace them.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] myArgs = {"arg1", "arg2"};
String sentence = "here is a text with :arg and :arg";
int counter = 0;
while (sentence.indexOf(":arg") != -1) {
   sentence = sentence.substring(0, sentence.indexOf(":arg")) + myArgs [counter] + sentence.substring(sentence.indexOf(":arg") + 4, sentence.length());
   counter++;
}
```